# How to provided a separate linking environment for a daemon

Tags: linux

I have this piece of software I'm required to install on my workstation. Let's call it "Yeti repellent". It supports OpenSUSE 15.3, but I am running Tumbleweed. I install the Yeti repellent and start the daemon, and it starts up! But something possessed me to check that all the binaries actually worked. I discovered that one of the binaries did, indeed, not work. So I I put `/path/to/yeti-repellent/lib/` into `yeti.conf` and drop it in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`. Now Yeti repellent works! And `zypper` is broken! So how I can isolate Yeti repellent for the purposes of linking without running it in a chroot or container?  The daemon is managed by Systemd, so maybe I can isolate it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify environment variables [inside systemd units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment=):

```
[Service]
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/yeti-repellent/lib:/usr/lib:/lib
```

It should be possible to specify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and have `/path/to/yeti-repellent/lib` be the first entry, such that yeti-repellent picks up that version of the library rather than the system version (which `zypper`, presumably, is built/linked against).

**Edit:**

The above approach might work for your particular use case, but it isn't the best practice. If you can run the application in a container, then that is probably the better approach (and, assuming this is an enterprise-y application, is probably more likely to be officially supported than hacking around dependencies with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

Comment: Unfortunately containers aren't an option for compliance reasons. Yeti repellent must run free and unfettered.